# Grammaticality of "help someone something"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, transitivity

A few times I've encountered phrases of the form "help yourself [something]", for example "help yourself some water". I consider this form to be ungrammatical, but I am not a native speaker. Is it correct to say so?

Comment: General Reference. It's *"Help yourself **to** some water"*, which should be asked on [English Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If *help* means *assist* and is followed by a verb, then that verb can appear with or without the infinitive-marker *to*:

> He helps me understand.
>   He helps me to understand.

Where *help* means *serve*, to give yourself a helping, it's followed by a noun or noun phrase as the direct object and it needs the preposition *to*:

> Help yourself to some water.